# Will Ubuntu amd64 run on my Laptop?

Tags: 64-bit

Google is no longer supporting 32 bit version of Chrome browser, at least that's what the message i get every time i open the browser is saying. I need to use chrome, and i need to get latest upgrades too. So, i guess i need to install 64 bit Ubuntu but i am not sure if it will work on my Laptop. This is the specification, can someone tell me if 64 bit run smoothly on my Laptop:

Ram - 2gb
Processor - Intel® Pentium(R) CPU B950 @ 2.10GHz × 2 
Graphics - ntel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2

Comment: The [instruction set for your CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/55627/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B950-2M-Cache-2_10-GHz) says that it is 64-bit, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the Intel B950 is a 64-bit processor so installing Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) should work fine and allow you to run 32 and 64-bit software...  Make a bootable flash drive and give it a test.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search shows that your processor should be good to run 64 bit.

[Look here under specifications.](http://ark.intel.com/m/products/55627/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B950-2M-Cache-2_10-GHz#@product/specifications)

Will it run smooth?  That depends on how you use it. I have run into a rare issue once or twice where I had to load 32 bit libraries to get something to work. But another Google of the issue led me to a fix for that.

Here's what I would do, either burn an amd64 Ubuntu ISO to disk or make a bootable USB stick if your system sports USB booting.  Start Ubuntu as a live CD rather than choosing to install and see how things work on it. If everything seems to run okay, you should be able to install with relative certainty that it will work for you.

Remember rule #1 though, Google is your best friend when you run into issues.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will run perfectly. Your system resembles mine and after doing a little driver research i found that your laptop is good to run Ubuntu. and google chrome will also run smoothly on it , no problems :)

Answer (score 1):

In usual cases, you can run 32-bit applications on 64-bit Ubuntu, but you won’t be fully utilizing your system. However, the vice versa is not true. You won’t be able to run 64-bit applications on a 32-bit machine (just imagine, you can place a small container into a big container, but you can’t do that the other way round). When installing applications in Synaptic, you might notice that some software comes with the 32-bit and 64 bit version (only shows up when you are using the 64-bit Ubuntu). You can just pick the one you want. Additionally, not all 32-bit applications will work in 64-bit machine, particularly for applications that require access to system hardware settings.